# Google apps script to get results in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google App Scripts and am trying to modify this script to return the results to a spreadsheet instead of the logger.

```
function myFunction() {
   const getFileList = (id, folders = []) => {
    const f = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    const fols = f.getFolders();
    let temp = [];
    while (fols.hasNext()) {
      const fol = fols.next();
      const files = fol.getFiles();
      let fileList = [];
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        const file = files.next();
        fileList.push({ name: file.getName(), id: file.getId() });
      }
      temp.push({
        name: fol.getName(),
        id: fol.getId(),
        parent: id,
        parentName: f.getName(),
        files: fileList,
      });
    }
    if (temp.length > 0) {
      folders.push(temp);
      temp.forEach((e) => getFileList(e.id, folders));
    }
    return folders;
  };

  const folderId = "###"; // Folder ID of the shared Drive.
  const res = getFileList(folderId);
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write json data to a google sheet using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141901/how-to-write-json-data-to-a-google-sheet-using-javascript)

Comment: @Carlos M Also I think that your comment is useful for OP's situation. So, I proposed a modified script by modifying a little from the proposed script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values from `getFileList(folderId)` to the Spreadsheet.

The value returned from `getFileList(folderId)` is the array including JSON object. So, in this case, it is required to convert from JSON object to an array for each element. For this, I also think that [Carlos M's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823610/google-apps-script-to-get-results-in-spreadsheet#comment119883893_67823610) is useful. But, for this, it is required to modify a little for putting values to Spreadsheet. Because the value from `getFileList(folderId)` is 2 dimensional array and each file in the subfolders is also included in an array. In this answer, I would like to propose the modified script for putting values to Spreadsheet.

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
const folderId = "###"; // Folder ID of the shared Drive.
const res = getFileList(folderId);
console.log(res);
```

##### To:

```
const folderId = "###"; // Folder ID of the shared Drive.
const res = getFileList(folderId);
console.log(res);

// I added below script.
const object = res.flat();
const headers = Object.keys(object[0]);
const values = object.flatMap(o => {
  const temp = [];
  headers.forEach(f => {
    if (f != "files") temp.push(o[f]);
  });
  return o.files.map(({name, id}) => temp.concat(name, id));
});
headers.pop();
headers.push("file(name)", "file(id)");
values.unshift(headers);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- When you run this modified script, the retrieved values are put to the active sheet.

#### Reference:

- Related thread

  - [How to write json data to a google sheet using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58141901)